# Questions about the obsolete versions

Tags: discussion

Does the questions about obsolete versions are removed or not in Ask Ubuntu?

I think these questions and answers to these questions are not useful nowadays.

Comment: Keep the old data. It is definitely relevant. Not everyone is running 13.10. I do ssh to a server still happily running 8.04, and run 10.04 and 12.04 on some of my machines.

Answer (score 6):

Many of those questions are useful; if you see a question that can still apply to a new version of Ubuntu you can edit it to make it more generic.

I usually try to answer in a way that's "future proof". It doesn't hurt to keep them around, most of our traffic comes from search engines and the freshest stuff usually comes up first in the results.

We don't need to remove old content, we just need to remove *wrong* content.

Comment: I agree with you, with the exception that this makes looking for my 12.04 a longer process. If there were an archive marked so, to handle obsolete systems, or wrong threads, which kept the comments _italic_which are useful intact; would this be possible? I meant to italicize which are useful.

Answer (score 0):

If an answer is **for one and only one** version of Ubuntu and that solution **doesn't work anymore** in recent versions, I don't see why it should stay. Now, generic questions and answer can stay. Just edit out the versions or add a title that reads:

---

### This only works from 13.04 onwards

---

For example, if the answer has/needs different instructions for some version of Ubuntu. If some instruction is only for a EOLed version (say 11.10) verify that it doesn't work anymore, correct if it's salvageable or edit out if it's useless.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 13.10, 13.04, 12.04 and 10.4 on different machines and ssh to a server that still runs 8.04 server. So any info on 8.04 is suddenly irrelevant?? I hope not! Keep the old info. You can edit it to say that is relevant only to a particular version but definitely keep it.

Comment: @haziz you as internet denizen should upgrade that 8.04 server. Everyone should upgrade their stuff.

Comment: It is not broken! Besides, I am not root on that server!